# Issue with building a haskell-stack postgresql project

Tags: postgresql, yesod, haskell-stack

I'm trying to use stack to set up the yesod-postgres template project on my Windows machine. Unfortunately, when I run `stack build` I get the following result:

```
pg-project-0.0.0: build
Preprocessing library pg-project-0.0.0...
In-place registering pg-project-0.0.0...
Preprocessing executable 'pg-project' for pg-project-0.0.0...
Linking .stack-work\dist\95439361\build\pg-project\pg-project.exe ...
C:/Users/Rik/AppData/Local/Programs/stack/i386-windows/ghc-7.10.3/mingw/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lpq
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

--  While building package pg-project-0.0.0 using:
      C:\stack_root\setup-exe-cache\i386-windows\setup-Simple-Cabal-1.22.5.0-ghc-7.10.3.exe --builddir=.stack-work\dist\95439361 build lib:pg-project exe:pg-project --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

I've added C:\PostgreSQL\bin to my PATH, and I'm using the 32-bit version of PostgreSQL 9.5.

Any help is appreciated.